# scp with short password

Tags: scp

when i tried to create public private key pair for password which length is less then 4 it does accept my password because of length

is it any option to use scp with short length passwords

Comment: You can create a key pair without a password.  Then when you connect with SSH (provided the keys are installed properly on both ends) it will not prompt you for a password.

Comment: i am planning to use in bash script , do you think it's ok without password

Comment: what/who are you connecting to, and do you have full physical control over you computer (such as a stationary home computer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short password is easy to crack and therefore of limited value. If you want to protect your key you should probably choose a longer password.

If you don't need that level of security you can create a key pair without pass phrase (for OpenSSH, just press return when you are prompted for the password during key pair generation).